# Detect any headset Play/Pause forward/backward volume up/down button tap on swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to build an Audio Player App! I can not figure out, how I can get my app responsible to Play/Pause forward/backward volume up/down button tap or click from any headphone or headset!
I found this page from apple! but it is not understandable for me! I like to have an example code!

Link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpremotecommand

Comment: Did you try the sample code on that page? You see the "playCommand" part, check if you try to play with your headset, it goes into that closure. For other commands, check https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpremotecommandcenter

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already have the class that will handle the media playback the rest is rather easy.

As mentioned in the link you provided, any event related to media is sent for the apps that are listening it doesn't matter where the event comes from (control center, headset...) that part is handled by the Media Player Framework

On the class you need to grab the command center of the MPF (Media player framework) and set the functions that will be triggered by the events, I will only show the one in the link you provided.

```swift
class MediaPlayer {
    let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()

    init() {
        // this is for the play command, check the docs for more commands
        commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] event in
            if self.player.rate == 0.0 { // <- is stopped?
                // do your stuff and say to the OS that everything worked
                return .success
            }
            // if the command does not run properly you must inform the OS
            return .commandFailed
        }
    }
}
```

There's some missing code that depends on your implementation, but what you want is here, now when something triggers the "play" command your app will detect it and if the player is not reproducing any media it will start.

You can see on the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpremotecommandcenter) more info about the MPRemoteCommandCenter and for more commands, that follow the same pattern.

Comment: thanks for your help and time! As I said I found that link! but I do not have any idea to make it work in my project! Let me send my project!

Comment: I am using AVAudioPlayer with loading my app! I can also make it working in button tap! it is not important now! I wanted give you an idea what I am doing! when view load it will start to play! I like pause or play it with headset tap!